# How do I check if my VM is using vhost-net driver for networking

Tags: networking, linux-kernel, kvm, virtio

In KVM, NIC model can be set to `virtio` (latest) or the older `e1000` (not recommended, emulated). In virtio, one has the option of using `vhost-net` driver or `qemu`.

vhost-net and qemu differs in how packets are sent from guest to host and subsequently sent to physical NIC.

> The vhost-net module is a kernel-level back end for virtio networking that reduces virtualization overhead by moving virtio packet processing tasks out of user space (the QEMU process) and into the kernel (the vhost-net driver). vhost-net is only available for virtio network interfaces. **If the vhost-net kernel module is loaded, it is enabled by default** for all virtio interfaces, but can be disabled in the interface configuration if a particular workload experiences a degradation in performance when vhost-net is in use. [cite](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/virtualization_deployment_and_administration_guide/sect-network_configuration-disabling_vhost_net)

My question is, how do one check if vhost-net module is loaded or not? Does the usual command `modinfo` work here as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see which kernel modules are loaded use the `lsmod` command.

You can use `grep` to pipe the output of `lsmod` to filter something more desirable.

e.g.

```
# lsmod | grep net
vhost_net              24576  10
vhost                  45056  1 vhost_net
tap                    24576  1 vhost_net
```

This host is using vhost_net kernel module - I happen to have 10 adapters configured, the output of `ifconfig` lists 10 vnet adapters.  The 10 in the `lsmod | grep` output is the number of times the kernel module is being used.